# how to get query parameters in first request in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am facing a problem in Angular. My application will be called by another web application and that application will send some query parameters which I need to access in my application and do some processing using those parameters. My Routing looks like

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foo',
    component: FooComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'bar',
    component: BarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'error',
    component: ErrorComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/foo',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/error',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

When I hit my application with `http://localhost:4200/?id=1234`, I am redirected to `http://localhost:4200/foo` without the query parameters. I tried creating a guard to access the params but no luck. For the rest of the routes, I know how to access parameters but don't know how to get that on the first URL hit. This looks like a normal use-case so wondering if anyone can guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the FooComponent to be displayed as your base URL

To do this try:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FooComponent
  },
  // others ...
  {
    path: 'foo',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

And in foo component to get the query string parameters

```js
ngOnInt(){
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
    const id = queryParams['id'];
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kieran. This did not work. parameters are shown as blank.

Answer (score 0):

In short: [you can't.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9921)

However you can specify your own `matcher` to redirect to a specific URL.
This does give you access to the query parameters.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: customMatcher,
    redirectTo: '/foo/:id',
  }
];
```

The matcher could extract the id. The essence is that the id needs to be extracted and put in the posParams field. The redirect path will then receive it as a named query parameter.

```
export function customMatcher(segments: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult {
    if (segments?.length === 1) {

       return {
         consumed: segments,
         posParams: { id: segments[0] },  
       };
       return null;
    }
 }
```

The above code does not work/ not tested. But I think if you put a breakpoint you will be able to exactly see how the id should be extracted.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks bvdb. I will try your approach. This looks like a very normal business scenario to get redirected from somewhere else. not sure why this is not supported.

Comment: @SandeepKumar apologies in advance, for not testing it. I took it from one of my previous projects.

Comment: @SandeepKumar apparently there's a big confusion about whether the position of the slash in the base level URL.  e.g.   http://example.com/base/?test vs http://example.com/base?test  And from what I've noticed this is even different if you do a ng build --prod --base /test/  or  ng build --prod --base /test  and to make it worse, it's different if you use an electron app. I personally use a different index.html for electron because of that. So really the base path is complicated. :-)

Comment: No problem mate. I dont have any other leads so will try all options. Thanks.

Comment: @SandeepKumar the previouse code example was too confusing I think. So, I replaced it with something that is more effective and shorter;